# How to elegantly customize the collection key name in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

1. For example, there is such a collection

```php
$phone_Id = $request->get('q');
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color->toArray();
dd($colors);
```

2. print result

```sh
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "name" => "red"
    "value" => "#fb6250"
    "created_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
    "pivot" => array:4 [▼
      "phone_id" => 1
      "color_id" => 8
      "created_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
      "updated_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 11
    "name" => "blue"
    "value" => "#202020"
    "created_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
    "pivot" => array:4 [▼
      "phone_id" => 1
      "color_id" => 11
      "created_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
      "updated_at" => "2019-05-29 01:42:51"
    ]
  ]
]
```

3. The end result I want is an array like this

```sh
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "text" => "red"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 11
    "text" => "blue"
  ]
]
```

4. So my current practice is like this.

```php
$data = [];
foreach ($colors as $key => $val) {
    $data[$key]['id'] = $val->id;
    $data[$key]['text'] = $val->name;
}
dd($data);
```

5. print result

```sh
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "text" => "red"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 11
    "text" => "blue"
  ]
]
```

> I want to know if there is a better and more beautiful implementation for this kind of demand in laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`->trasform(..)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-transform):

```php
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color;

$colors->transform(function ($color) {
    return [
        'id' => $color->id,
        'text' => $color->name,
    ];
});
```

**Edit:** thanks for the correct answer and upvotes, but I'd like to point out that OP came to a much more elegant solution using query builder's `->get(..)` and renaming the columns:

```php
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color()->get(['id', 'name as text'])->toArray();
```

Comment: thank you very much, I came up with an easier way.  
```php
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color()->get(['id', 'name as text'])->toArray(); 
```
  It only takes a piece of code to implement

Comment: Oh, nice yeah that's elegant

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Collection have an `->only()` method and `->map()` which can be used like this:

```
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color()->only(['id', 'name'])toArray();

$colors->map(function($color) {
    $color->text = $color->name;
    unset($color->text);
})
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-only

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map

Comment: HI, thank you very much， 
```php
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color->only(['id', 'name']);
dd($colors);
```
resule :
```shell
Collection {#861 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: Your Welcome @Angu. If this was the answer you are looking for you can tell people it is answered by selecting the tick.

Comment: According to your tips, I came up with the easiest way. $colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color()->get(['id', 'name as text'])->toArray();

Comment: Sorry, the collection is empty because you have to write color as color()

Comment: Thank you very much, your method does have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select('id', 'name')`

Try this one.

```
$colors = Phone::find($phone_Id)->color()->select('id', 'name')->get()->toArray()

dd($colors);
```

Comment: I might be mistaken however she seems to be using a relationship on the results of find which means that `->select()` method is not available

Comment: error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select does not exist.

Comment: Great, this code may apply to the parent model. YOU CAN USE THE ANSWER OF JOSH above https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370088/4551227

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select does not exist.  Because color needs to be written as color()

Comment: I see, thank you. I just realized the difference between color and color()

color - variable
color() - instance

If I'm not mistaken.